# PInvoke C#: Function takes pointer to function as argument

Tags: c#, pinvoke, param

I'd like to access this function in my c# code, is this possible? so in the end the c++ code would call my function and also apply the struct called "sFrameofData".

C++ Code:

```
//The user supplied function will be called whenever a frame of data arrives.
DLL int Cortex_SetDataHandlerFunc(void (*MyFunction)(sFrameOfData* pFrameOfData));
```

Would this work perhaps?

C# Code:

```
[DllImport("Cortex_SDK.dll")]
public extern static int Cortex_SetDataHandlerFunc(ref IntPtr function(ref IntPtr pFrameOfData) );
```

Comment: did you test this? can't you try it yourself and tell us how it goes?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You want to use a delegate that matches the method signature of your "MyFunction" C++ method.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MyFunctionDelegate(IntPtr frame);

[DllImport("Cortex_SDK.dll")]
public extern static int Cortex_SetDataHandlerFunc(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]MyFunctionDelegate functionCallback);
```

Comment: Yup.  [MarshalAs] is not needed here, it is already assumed.  The *frame* argument is either *ref* or IntPtr, not both.

Comment: seems like i had issues with crashes unless i put the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvenction.Cdecl)] Thank you

Comment: I'd like to add that simply calling `Cortex_SetDataHandlerFunc(MyFunc)` where `MyFunc` is defined as `void MyFunc(IntPtr frame) {...}` isn't enough. `Cortex_SetDataHandlerFunc(MyFunc)` is essentially `Cortex_SetDataHandlerFunc(new MyFunctionDelegate(MyFunc))` and the anonymous delegate object `new MyFunctionDelegate(MyFunc)` can be sometimes disposed by GC before `MyFunctionDelegate` returns. In this case you need to create a delegate object explicitly to avoid it to be GCed: `var myDele = new MyFunctionDelegate(MyFunc); Cortex_SetDataHandlerFunc(myDele);`

Comment: Hi, I'm in similar situation where I have to pass method pointer in another method. I understood Marshaling part. how would you call this method now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the proper way but I don't think is enough to use ref IntPtr for functions and structures...

see here for some help: [C# P/Invoke: Marshalling structures containing function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969049/c-p-invoke-marshalling-structures-containing-function-pointers)