# C# Marshalled Callbacks

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

I am trying to Marshall c call backs that are in a struct. I am pretty sure I have everything correct, but when using my C# example I don't get events, when using c++ I do get events.

Here is the C#

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("Some.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int SetCallbacks(Callbacks callBack);


    static Callbacks Callback = new Callbacks { DataArrived = DataArrived, SendFailure = SendFailure };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetCallbacks(Callback);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void DataArrived(uint id, IntPtr data)
    {

    }

    static void SendFailure(uint id, uint id2, IntPtr data)
    {

    }
}



[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Callbacks
{
    public DataArrived DataArrived;
    public SendFailure SendFailure;
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void DataArrived(uint id,   IntPtr data);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void SendFailure(uint id, uint id2, IntPtr ulpData);
```

This is from the C header file.

```
struct callBacks
{
    void (*dataArriveNotif) (unsigned int,    void*);
    void (*sendFailureNotif) (unsigned int, unsigned int, void*);
}

int SetCallbacks(callBacks callBacks);
```

Here is the working c++.

```
struct callBacks;
callbacks.dataArriveNotif = &dataArriveNotif;
callbacks.sendFailureNotif = &sendFailureNotif;
SetCallbacks(callBacks);
```

Comment: Use the debugger, enable unmanaged code debugging.  Set breakpoints on the C code that makes the callback call (not visible) and the C# DataArrived method.

Comment: I actually stepped into the SetCallbacks and the struct has all Null values, how did that happen?

Comment: I don't know.  Experiment with Marshal.StructureToPtr to see if the structure marshals correctly.

Comment: @Will What is `Some.dll`, PInvoke library? If yes, where can I download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything dealing with the delegate was actually correct. I simplified the senario a little bit in the example.

```
public static extern int SetCallbacks(Callbacks callBack);
```

was actually

```
public static extern int SetCallbacks(String[] array, Callbacks callBack);
```

The string array had lots of trailing 0's at the end. Which made the callback struct all nulls. I gave up trying to marshal the string[] the correct way and just made it a Intptr and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

so very similar to this question asked yesterday...

[PInvoke C#: Function takes pointer to function as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235445/pinvoke-c-function-takes-pointer-to-function-as-argument/5235587#5235587)

Comment: I actually have [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] attribute on the delegates. I also tried changing the struct to IntPtr's instead of the delegates and using Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate. It still doesn't work.