# Pass callback pointer from unmanaged C++ DLL to C# dll

Tags: c#, c++, callback, interop, unmanaged

I have unmanaged C++ DLL (MFC Extension DLL to be precise). 
This DLL loads the C# DLL and calls its method Start() as shown below.
All this works.

C++ ==============================================

```
BOOL CForwarder::Start()
{
    return InitMyManagedFlex();
}



// CForwarder member functions
BOOL CForwarder::InitMyManagedFlex()
{
    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    IForwarderPtr pIFwd(__uuidof(MyForwarder));

    long lResult = 0;
    VARIANT_BOOL ret = FALSE;
    BSTR bstr = AsciiToBSTR("AAA");

    // Call the Add method.
    pIFwd->Start(bstr, &ret);

    SysFreeString(bstr);

    wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", ret);

    // Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();

    return (ret == VARIANT_TRUE) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}


// Interface declaration.
public interface IForwarder
{
    bool StartCmd(string msg);
};
```

==================================================================

The C# class in C# DLL looks like this:

```
namespace MyManagedFlex
{

    public class MyForwarder:IForwarder
    {
        public bool StartCmd(string msg)
        {
            return StartSending();
        }

        private bool StartSending()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Interface declaration.
    public interface IForwarder
    {
        bool StartCmd(string msg);
    };

}
```

Here is the basic question: How do I pass a callback function in Start() and how and what I implement in C++ and C# so that C# could call back C++ DLL at any time it desires and pass some parameters.

Comment: You need a delegate.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250478/c-sharp-marshalled-callbacks

Comment: Since you are using COM, it makes sense for you to implement a COM interface and pass that to the C# code.

Comment: @jdweng That question discusses the reverse problem. There the asker is defining the callback in C# code, and passing a delegate to the C code. In this question, the asker wants to define the callback in the C++ code and pass that function pointer to the C# code. In the question you link to, the C# process is the executable, linking to the unmanaged C DLL via pinvoke. But in this question the C++ MFC DLL hosts the C# assembly using COM to load that C# assembly.

Comment: David, your last comment is correct, but I stilldon't have a solution. I tried to define this in Forwarder.cpp class:

typedef void(*functionPointer)(const char* data);


functionPointer myFunc; // This is the actual function that is called from C# DLL (such as MyManagedFlex.dll)
void CForwarder::CallbackFromCSharp(const char* data)
{
 TRACE(data);
}

Then I tried to call inside InitMyManagedFlex

 myFunc = &CallbackFromCSharp;
 pIFwd->Start(bstr, myFunc, &ret);

But the last 2 lines won't compile...