# How to evaluate reference of IDebugProperty2?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How to get the address of the object in a `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.IDebugProperty2`?
Prepending `&` (`&expression`) isn't solution because I'll lose children of a property, but it is what I want.

I'm getting property2 via `IDebugExpression2::EvaluateSync` with variable name as an expression.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25464740/8335151).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a variable inside is a pointer (variable for reference type) it returns address.

```cs
if (property2.GetMemoryContext(out var memoryContext2) != (int) HResults.S_OK || memoryContext2 == null)
  return 0;

var info = new CONTEXT_INFO[1];
memoryContext2.GetInfo(enum_CONTEXT_INFO_FIELDS.CIF_ADDRESS, info);

return long.Parse(info[0].bstrAddress.Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```