# Call C++ function from C# which gives value frequently

Tags: c#, delegates

I need to show a live data on text field in C#.basically whenever a value changes, below c++ function under LTscriptenginedll.dll

```
ConnectLiveData(void* pCallBack, const char** pszTagNames, const int** pnTagAddress,
        bool bdiscconectConnection, bool bPyRequest)
```

gives new value .
I need to create a C# function which will call and takes value from this C++ function everytime value changes in function.I tried but so for I am still struggling.

Below is my code.

```
     public unsafe float StartLiveInfo(string tagNameFromRequest)
    {
        string tagName = tagNameFromRequest;//"Motor_1.OutPut.VI";
        byte[] tagNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tagName);
        IntPtr tagNamePtr = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(tagNameByte, 0);


        IntPtr[] tagNameIntPtr = new IntPtr[2];
        tagNameIntPtr[0] = tagNamePtr;
        tagNameIntPtr[1] = IntPtr.Zero;

        int tagValueTemp = 0;
        int*[] tagValuePtr = new int*[2];
        tagValuePtr[0] = &tagValueTemp;
        tagValuePtr[1] = null;
        float test;

        fixed (int** tagValue1 = tagValuePtr)
        {

            fixed (IntPtr* tagName1 = tagNameIntPtr)
            {
                try
                {
                    myCallBackPtr obj = new myCallBackPtr(CallMethod);
                    int finalTagValue = ConnectLiveData(obj, tagName1, tagValue1,false,true);
                    test = Convert.ToSingle(*tagValue1[0]);
                    return test;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I have called dll function and using delegate.

```
    public delegate void myCallBackPtr();
    [DllImport("LTscriptenginedll.dll")]
    public static extern unsafe int ConnectLiveData(myCallBackPtr ps,IntPtr* test, int** temp,bool bdiscconectConnection, bool bPyRequest);
```

Here is callMethod

```
        public static void CallMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("callbackcalled");
    }
```

I am calling this **StartLiveInfo** function from main.aspx on buttonclick event and showing return value in text field.

below it the code:

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float retValue = oraDal.StartLiveInfo("M1.Speed");
        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(retValue);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working ? Might help to diagnose, if you've got an exception / details on the error. And if someone could throw up a dummy c++ project to test it out, I'd be willing to invest some time in trying to figure it out.

Comment: And did you check : [PInvoke C#: Function takes pointer to function as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5235549/2245256) ?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to apply the [UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedfunctionpointerattribute?view=net-6.0) to your `myCallbackPtr` delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is add C++ code into C# Code, you will need to do some steps:

1. At solution explorer, right-click in your Project and go to Properties;
2. In the Build menu, go to General sub-menu and check the option "Unsafe code" like this image bellow:
   [image]
3. If you end these steps above, good luck! You'll may add C++ code into your C# project without impediments.

Comment: The C++ function of the OP is external (in another DLL that is called through `DllIMport`), you do NOT need to enable unsafe to make those calls. You might need it if your workflow required you to to calculations on pointer, but most of the usual interactions can be done through IntPtr... And OP seems to already have this enabled (see the unsafe in their method's signature)

Comment: But check the code shared in the question: the method is declared with `unsafe` modified access and contains C++ code and calculations into IntPtr, the unsafe check marked is required.

Comment: Yes, but as the issue is not that the code won't build, one can assume the flag is already defined. And that's regular if not uncommon C# code, not C++, he's just tossing some unsafe pointers around :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the DLL located in the same directory that your executable is in, so that at runtime it can actually find and load the DLL containing your c++ function.