# C# call method from C++ class

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I'm trying to integrate with a windows based api using c-sharp and I've run into this issue.

The api sends me a pointer to a struct that holds a bunch of virtual methods

```
struct CApiInterface
{
   virtual int __stdcall Version(void);
   ...
}
```

My question is, how can I call methods off this in C#? I'd like to do something like:

```
CApiInterface _api;

public void Start(CApiInterface* api)
{
_api = api;
}

...

public void SomeOtherMethod()
{
_api.version();
}
```

I would like to stay out of CLI/C++ if at all possible, if this is even possible to begin with.

Comment: AFAIK, unless you want to write a native COM shim, you'll need to use C++/CLI here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969049/c-p-invoke-marshalling-structures-containing-function-pointers) for an example of someone else who did the same thing. It seems to revolve around using delegates marked with the `UmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute`.

Comment: I glossed over the `virtual` part, since the question originally was "C# method from *C struct*"

Comment: I'm actually surprised that this works for your situation. I wouldn't have expected it to.