# Is there a way to get function pointer for extern method in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, function-pointers, dllimport

I want to get the function pointer (ie `IntPtr`) for an `extern` method such as:

```
[DllImport("DbgHelp.dll")]
static extern void SymFunctionTableAccess64(IntPtr process, ulong addrBase);
```

which, then also be used as a parameter for an `extern` method such as:

```
[DllImport("DbgHelp.dll")]
static extern int StackWalk64(......., IntPtr FunctionTableAccessRoutine, ....);
```

I know I can use `LoadLibrary` and then `GetProcAddress`, or wrap the function in a C# method and then use `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` for a function pointer. I wonder if we can retrieve the function pointer directly from P/Invoke mechanism, because, during runtime, functions will already be loaded via `DllImport`. Just to note, my problem is not specific to `StackWalk64` or any DbgHelp.dll functions.

Comment: Take a look at this article.
[Marshalling structures containing function pointers][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969049/c-sharp-p-invoke-marshalling-structures-containing-function-pointers?rq=1

Maybe it helps.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235445/pinvoke-c-function-takes-pointer-to-function-as-argument) could help you as well.

Comment: "...during runtime, functions will already be loaded via `DllImport`..." Actually, this won't happen until the function is called from managed code for the first time, which loads the DLL dynamically. So if you're not actually calling it, `LoadLibrary` is definitely necessary.

Comment: I don't know what you're up to with the `StackWalk64` and other such APIs. But just in case you want to write some sort of managed debugger for native apps (including just grabbing stacktraces for running processes), you might be better off encapsulating all that logic in a native DLL by itself, providing "easiy" DllImport-entrypoints for your managed code (been there, done that :-|).

Comment: The return type is IntPtr, not void.  Don't use pinvoke for this, and especially not GetProcAddress(), there are [friendly wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx) for the DbgHelp api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GetProcAddress` to get the address of an external unmanaged function.

There's no problem doing this. Functions are not loaded as such. Modules are loaded. Once a module has been loaded, `GetProcAddress` just performs a lookup in the export table of the module. If you know that the module is already loaded then you don't need to call `LoadLibrary` again. You can use `GetModuleHandle`. Not that a call to `LoadLibrary` presents any problem either really. If the module is already loaded, then a call to `LoadLibrary` simply increases the reference count of the module, and returns its handle.

Mind you, what you are attempting doesn't look suited to p/invoke. Native code is surely more appropriate.